# Trying to create new row in table. Getting "column 'accountId' does not exist". Looks like a new column is being returned. I don't need this column

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm working in insomnia trying to create a new account entry.

I'm getting the following line in terminal. At the end you can see that `accountId` column is returned and I don't need it.

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "accounts" ("id","name","userId","type","limit","balance","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING "id","name","userId","type","limit","balance","minPayment","dueDate","createdAt","updatedAt","accountId";
```

Because of it I get this error in insomnia:

```
column "accountId" does not exist
```

Below is the Account model

```
'use strict'
const { Model } = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Account extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Account.hasMany(models.Transaction, { foreignKey: 'accountId' })
      Account.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
    }
  }
  Account.init(
    {
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      type: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      limit: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      balance: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      minPayment: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      dueDate: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Account',
      tableName: 'accounts'
    }
  )
  return Account
}
```

Below is the User Model

```
'use strict'
const { Model } = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      User.hasMany(models.Account, { foreignKey: 'accountId' })
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      middleName: DataTypes.STRING,
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          isEmail: true
        }
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
      tableName: 'users'
    }
  )
  return User
}
```

I've tried updating my Account model trying to remove the foreign key `accountId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in the User's association:
You wrote:

```js
User.hasMany(models.Account, { foreignKey: 'accountId' })
```

The correct one:

```js
User.hasMany(models.Account, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
```